# wsdl2objc - had to manually modify the soap message to make it work

Tags: objective-c, web-services

I tried to call a web service from iphone. I used wsdl2objc to generate the stub. To make the web service call really work, I had to manually modify the soap message. Any better framework for ios soap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had success with [SudzC](http://sudzc.com/) in recent projects, which will read a WSDL and generate a complete set of Objective-C (or Actionscript, or Javascript) classes, with supporting frameworks and an Xcode project, for working with your web service.  Is that what you're looking for?